# How to get pushed or pulled element on Deployd

Tags: deployd

I'm interacting my deployd server app over HTTP.

I am adding to an array using $push.

Is there a way to get the value pushed to the array?

Example:

```
PUT /upvotes/foo

{
   "stories" : {"$push": "bar"}
}
```

On Put Script:

```
var pushedElement = ??? // I should be able to get "bar"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can access it in the request's body.

The body is stored inside the context object - `ctx`. Try this in your put script event,

```
var pushedElement = ctx.body.stories.$push
```

From deployd's docs,

> ctx.body `{Object}` :
>   The body of the request if sent as **application/json**
>   or **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.